# How great should my rep be before I start waving it around?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, flair

I have just started on Stack Overflow (and think it is great).

At what point does one's reputation get big enough to warrant putting a 'flair' link on their blog?  Really what I am asking is what is a decent reputation to attain before linking to your Stack Overflow profile?

Comment: Welcome to MSO jkode :)

Comment: I would say when you get 10k+. It's really not that hard. I got it in 55 days.

Answer (score 13):

I would say it doesn't matter. Displaying your flair indicates that you are a member of the community and it will get others to visit the site. I have had 900+ rep on Stack Overflow since I joined a year ago, and it has never affected whether I display flair or not.

Answer (score 11):

The average reputation of a user is around 500.  So, unless you are proud of being below average, then I'd call that an absolute minimum.

Comment: LOL - Good answer!

Answer (score 10):

If you're proud of your reputation. Then flair up!

Comment: Even if it's only 1 rep!

Comment: If that's what you're proud of.. for some strange reason.

Answer (score 7):

I started showing my flair shortly after I joined SO, even though I only had a couple hundred rep. It's not my rep count that I'm proud of, it's the fact that I'm part of such a great community!

Really, I'm proud to be linking to SO. The more great people who discover SO, the better (for those people and for the overall SO community).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Ólafur. However, I don't consider a reputation under 2/3K decent enough to be proud of and to share it :)

Comment: Then vote me up :P

Comment: Me! Me! Me!

Comment: You! You! You!