# Starting with which reputation should I use the "got flair" feature?

Tags: discussion, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow User Flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18739/stack-overflow-user-flair)

Starting with which reputation is it "not embarrasing" to use the 'Got Flair' feature?
I thought about adding it to my website (as I'm currently looking for a job), but I'm afraid that the rating of 1400 won't impress anyone.

So my question is: what rating is considered by you as a 'good rating', that would help you impress future employers?

---

Thank you so much for expressing your opinion, and for pointing me to the other question (for which this one is indeed a duplicate). It was very helpful for me.

Comment: Anything under 10k is pitiable.

Comment: Also, reputation is an arbitrary number that should not impress any employers that a competent person would want to vote for. Seriously, "This guy spends ~8 hours a day answering questions on a Q&A site! I'm sure he doesn't have any attention span problems! Let's hire him before someone else does!" Does that sound like someone you'd want to work for? In related news, I got my current job by showing my employer a shiny laser until he hired me.

Comment: You are not allowed to use it below 100K. Jon would be offended otherwise.

Comment: When Jon casts an offensive flag, you not only immediately have your comment deleted and lose 100 reputation, but $100 is withdrawn from your bank account and is donated to the Wayback Machine in Jeff Atwood's name.

Comment: @Welbog - are you an optometrist?

Comment: @Jon B: No, I'm a laserographer. I thought that was obvious from my profile.

Comment: Grrr. I wonder whether I should take the '10k' seriously.

Comment: 10k is not some magical border. Some employers might take it serious even at 1k, some might not care about it even at 100k. There's no general rule on this.

Comment: @Anna: If you take anything seriously which is related with the four sites of the trilogy, then you are doing it wrong!

Comment: @John Smithers: **Silliness is paramount!**

Comment: @John, how can anyone take seriously a trilogy that has four of something?

Comment: @Pavel Shved: I dunno, *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* is fairly well-regarded, and there are **five** entries in that trilogy! :)

Comment: @Jon B: No, I'm pretty sure he's a pessimist.

Comment: I feel as if I entered a group with its own sense of humor I don't yet get :-)

Comment: We don't have sense, period!

Comment: @Anna: On Meta, we do have our own unique senses of humor. However, in response to your question, rep != expertise, and any employer who thinks it does is **not** someone you want to work for. Employers like that probably still use lines-of-code as a positive work metric. Rep indicates *participation* here, not any actual knowledge.

Comment: Good luck waiting for more answers now that the question is close! Bwaahahahaha! *(Damn it, text needs a better way to express my amazing laughter.)*

Comment: A four digit reputation is something to be proud of -- it shows you have stuck around for quite some time and you didn't just fluke out on a few answers. It shows you know *something*. However, some of us only know about ponies and waffles; thankfully there's lots of those questions around still!

Comment: @Termifish: Or, according to the publishers, 6 books in the Hitchhiker's Guide Trilogy. And Another Thing carries the subtitle Book Six of Three.

Comment: @Macha: I forgot about *And Another Thing,* I gave up after the fifth was such a disappointment ...

Comment: @Termifish: Don't tell me you take *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* seriously?

Comment: @fretje: I never leave home without a towel, if that's what you're asking. :) And I take it more seriously than I take Meta.

Answer (score 5):

I view flair primarily as a way to show your love for Stack Overflow. It doesn't have a start rep if you really like promoting Stack Overflow on your page.

Answer (score 4):

If you're proud of your rep and want to use the flair feature, use it, no matter how much rep you have. There's no good or bad reputation here; the simple fact that you're on SO shows you're passionate about programming and want to learn and help others.

Answer (score 2):

My current boss doesn't have a tiniest idea of what the numbers on the flair mean, but, having seen it, he said that being in a Q&A site community is cool.

Therefore, I think, the numbers hardly matter unless they really look miserable.  I think that if your rep count ends with `k` (that happens if you have `10k` or more) it definitely isn't too few to show your involvement.

Comment: That's the thing. I don't have over 10k. I only have 1,400.
But I guess you guys are right, and just being a member is something to be proud of.