# Got Flair -- when should I start displaying it?

Tags: discussion, reputation, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How great should my rep be before I start waving it around?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18739/how-great-should-my-rep-be-before-i-start-waving-it-around)

How high should one's flair score get before one starts to display it?

Comment: When you have a place to show it off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As high as you want. There is a reason that it's not a feature unlocked by your reputation. If you want to show off your 250 reputation, go right ahead.

Answer (score 26):

If you're happy with your progress, show your flair

If you're happy with your progress, show your flair

If you're happy with your progress

and you surely want to show it,

If you're happy with your progress, show your flair.

Comment: Damn you for getting a certain song stuck in my head (+1 BTW).

Answer (score 4):

[37](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151804/quotes?qt0386910)

Comment: Good reference, but I think 15 was the actual minimum allowed.  ;)

Comment: @Bill: "What do you think of a person who only does the bare minimum?" ;)

Comment: Man, I walked right into that one.  :)

Comment: And here I thought that's be a link to Clerks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy with your progress, show your flair.

If you're happy with your progress, show your flair.

If you're happy with your progress,

and you really want to impress...

If you're happy with your progress, show your flair!

*Yes, it's a ripoff of Gamecat's answer, but I was really bothered that the original didn't rhyme.*

Answer (score 1):

If you have to ask, it's not high enough yet.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 42.